# Fragment getArguments() is returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

For some reason my fragment bundle which contains an array of strings is coming up null in the oncreate method of my fragment. I am trying to pass an array of urls when creating the fragment so that it renders different images in the imageviews when I feed it different image urls. I did this initially in the constructor, but android didn't like the fact that I was using a constructor that was not a default constructor. I'm assuming the error might be comming from the fact that the fragment's oncreate method is being called before the bundle is passed to the fragment, but I don't know how to pass the information into the fragment sooner without passing through a constructor.

Here is the code where the fragments are being instantiated.

```
private void initViewPager() {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tabNames.length; i++)
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        ImageViewerFragment imageViewerFragment = new ImageViewerFragment();
        listFragments.add(imageViewerFragment);
        switch(tabNames[i])
        {
            case "All":
                bundle.putStringArray("urls", URLS.randomURLs);
                break;
            case "Zombie":
                bundle.putStringArray("urls", URLS.zombieURLS);
                break;
            case "Captain":
                bundle.putStringArray("urls", URLS.captainURLS);
                break;
            case "Awesome":
                bundle.putStringArray("urls", URLS.awesomeURLS);
                break;
        }
    }

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

My Fragment Class

```
public class ImageViewerFragment extends Fragment {
    GridView mGridView;
    ImageAdapter mImageAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageviewerfragment_layout, container, false);

        mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), getArguments().getStringArray("urls"));
        mGridView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you didn't set your `bundle` into a fragment. You didn't call `imageViewerFragment.setArguments(bundle);`

Comment: yeah, I just realized it too, Thanks.